# Android API Usage

Tags: android, google-api, google-maps-android-api-2

This might sound like stupid question...

If an Android app is using Maps API to use user location, do all the users use the same quota or do each logged-in user use their own quota?

Is there a way to code it so the app automatically gets the user to setup his/her own api key and use the app with his/her own free quota? For example, some sort of authentication with a gmail account that uses the gmail account's free quota. Every user will then have their own Maps API usage for free, is that possible?

Comment: See: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-limits

Answer (score 1):

No, your app doesn't have any quota for users. So you don't need to setup API key for each user.

Here is details ([usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-limits)):

> The following APIs do not have usage limits:
>
> Google Earth API
>   **Google Maps APIs for Android**
>   Google Maps APIs for iOS
>   Google Maps Embed API

Comment: What I mean is that... Is there a way to set it up so it prompts the user for his/her own login and then use the user's identity to access the resources?

That way if the app grows to 10 million users, each user will have his/her own free quota.